# Kafka gruop consumer is not created

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have started a consumer in a consumer group using following command

```
ldnpsr000001131$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic rent_test --property group.id=rent_test auto.commit.enable=true auto.commit.interval.ms=100
```

as I understand, above command will create a consumer group named rent_test, and commtted offset every 100 ms. However, when I tried to list all of the consumer group, the group "rent_test" is not presented.

```
ldnpsr000001131$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list  --zookeeper localhost:2181
console-consumer-68623
console-consumer-18287
console-consumer-45392
test
console-consumer-9009
KafkaMirror-test
console-consumer-25049
kafka-mirror
console-consumer-61946
console-consumer-940
console-consumer-11318
KafkaMirror
console-consumer-43035
console-consumer-99202
consumer-test
console-consumer-42642
console-consumer-19085
console-consumer-7142
KafkaMirror-test-1
console-consumer-82299
console-consumer-81448
console-consumer-26487
console-consumer-71474
flink
console-consumer-4692
```

Please advise?

Comment: What Kafka version so you use?

Comment: I am using `kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1` version @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: use option --bootstrap-server and not --zookeeper -- in kafka 0.9 and 0.10 offsets are not stored in ZK anymore.

Comment: I have rerun the adjusted command, but still no consumer group shown
`ldnpsr000001131$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe  -group rent_test --new-consumer
Consumer group `rent_test` does not exist or is rebalancing.
ldnpsr000001131$
` @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: the following command seems to be correct
`bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list  --zookeeper localhost:2181`
What I was missing is that I should have put the `group.id=rent_test` as the part config file instead of having it in-line.

Comment: I just realised I was using old consumer that is why it is still present at zookeeper @MatthiasJ.Sax

Answer (score 1):

If you are using old consumer, do not specify group.id in `property`. In 0.10.0.1, you have to specify it in a consumer config file and set `consumer.config`:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zkHost:2181 --topic test-topic --consumer.config <config file path>
```